# TRYING to subtract days from datetime and convert it to a string

Tags: python, string, datetime, strftime

From what I've seen this should be working even if it's not the prettiest. I've tried plenty of things but doesn't seem to work with anything and best I've been able to do is change the error message lol.

```py
try:
     date = dt.datetime.now()
     d1 = date - timedelta(days=1)
     d1.strftime('%Y%m%d')
     url = 'http://regsho.finra.org/FNQCshvol' + d1 + '.txt'
```

Comment: Welcome. What error message do you get?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Can you provide some more information, Error message, what you have tried etc

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime as dt

date = dt.datetime.now()
d1 = date - timedelta(days=1)
d1 = d1.strftime('%Y%m%d')          # I changed this line
url = 'http://regsho.finra.org/FNQCshvol' + d1 + '.txt'
```

strftime() returns the string, it does not convert the date itself to a string.

Comment: Thank u very much i knew it had to be something so easy i was missing

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little. There were a couple of mistake in it and it wasn't running.
The main problem you were running into is you were trying to concatenate a string with a datetime object. You applied the `strftime` correctly but you didn't save the string. That string you can concatenate with another string.

```
import datetime as dt

date = dt.datetime.now()
d1 = date - dt.timedelta(days=1)
d1_string = d1.strftime('%Y%m%d')
url = 'http://regsho.finra.org/FNQCshvol{timestamp}.txt'.format(timestamp=d1_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you don't assign result of `datetime.strftime()` to a variable. Solution is simple:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current_date = datetime.now()                     # store current date and time
required_date = current_date - timedelta(days=1)  # substitute 1 day
str_date = required_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')       # apply formatting
url = f'http://regsho.finra.org/FNQCshvol{str_date}.txt'
```

You can also do it in one line <s>*(which makes code much less readable)*</s>:

```
url = f"http://regsho.finra.org/FNQCshvol{(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y%m%d')}.txt"
```